# I am writing a C program and getting message 'Segmentation fault (core dumped) '

Tags: c

The program is to find out the smallest positive number which is not in the array. When I try to test my code, it shows the message 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. I am new to program c, are there anyone can help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int n = 5;
int i, j, k, x = 1, temp;
int array[] = {5, 1, 4, 5, 7};

void swap(){
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

void sorting(){
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                swap();
            }
        }
    }
}

void checking(){
    sorting();
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++){
        if (x != array[k]){
            printf('%d',array[k]);
            break;
        }
            else x++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    checking();
}
```

Comment: Hint: what does `j` equal when `i` equals `4` in your `for` loops in the `sorting()` method?

Comment: `printf('%d',array[k]);` rather than `printf("%d",array[k]);`, when _printf_ will try to read the format you will have a problem ...

Comment: @Tau no matter, because of `j < n;` loop condition.

Comment: ah, right.  forgot about that.

Comment: And you didn't get any compiler warnings for this line: `printf('%d', array[k]);`?

Comment: Compiler warnings are your friend.

Comment: Why ae you using global variables?

Comment: oh, I understand why this problem occurs....but now I have to deal with another problem in the sorting function.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 5):

The print part:

```
printf('%d',array[k]);
```

Needs double quotes:

```
printf("%d",array[k]);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].